# Ending a macro when autofilter has no matches

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have a macro set up to filter data by year, quarter, mobile (yes / no) with the end goal being that it  creates a schedule document to show what is in Q1 - Q4 for each year from a subset of data.

The issue I am having is that once it has filtered the first two variables, if there are no matches for the third (value to match is ü) then it negates everything and just copies all the raw data from the sheet as if no filters were applied.

```
    Sheets("ChangeLog").Select 
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AP$2040").AutoFilter Field:=36, Criteria1:="4"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AP$2040").AutoFilter Field:=35, Criteria1:="2020"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AP$2040").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="ü"
Range("A3:A2041").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("!PIPELINE_TEMPLATE").Select
Range("N77").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

It then continues this for various filter criteria but all follow the same pattern. Ideally I want it to end the sub if it can't find "ü"

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Mark

Comment: It works if you include the column headers in the range to copy, i.e. `Range("A2:A2041").Select`. But I guess you don't want to do that(?).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Simon,

We actually managed to figure it out using an IF after the autofilters.

```
    vRows = Sheets(shtChangeLog).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If vRows > 2 Then
```